# Cannot access a disposed object error on one workstation only

Tags: c#, .net-core, networkstream, objectdisposedexception

I have an odd problem.  I get this random error on a web app in c#, net8:
`System.ObjectDisposedException HResult=0x80131622 Message=Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.`

I have tested this on two workstations and it only happens on one of them. I seems to be random and can occur when the page is open but idle.

I'm not doing anything with keyboard or mouse -- answering phone or getting coffee. Just sitting there and this error pops up. But, again, this only happens on one of the two workstations where I'm running identical code.

Any ideas would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: We need to se some code.

Comment: Do you have any classes where the dispose pattern is implemented? Is it implemented correctly?

Comment: Neil: No I do not.  But even so, why would it present itself on one workstation and not another?

Magnus:  This issue is so random and can happen on most any page. I would not know what code to share.

Thanks guys!